# Get Vuex store reference in cypress with vue-cli

Tags: cypress, vue-cli-3

I'm following along [this](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2017/11/28/testing-vue-web-application-with-vuex-data-store-and-rest-backend/) tutorial to get the vuex store in cypress while running e2e tests.

As I use vue-cli (@vue/cli 4.3.1), with the [@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypress](https://cli.vuejs.org/core-plugins/e2e-cypress.html#injected-commands).
As of this setup, I don't have an app.js, rather a main.js.

But if I put the needed code in the main.js, it does not work:

```
/**
 * Start APP
 */
const app = new Vue({
    router,
    render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');

if (window.Cypress) {
    console.log('Running in Cypress');

    // only available during E2E tests
    window.app = app;
} else {
    console.log('NOT Running in Cypress');
}
```

If I run it from cypress, I doesn't log anything from main.js to the console.

In cypress, when I try to get the store

```
cy.window().its('app.$store')
```

I get the error:

```
Timed out retrying: cy.its() errored because the property: app does not exist on your subject.
```

How can I get it running with vue-cli?